# What happened to S.A.T.A.N. (a.k.a. S.A.N.T.A.)

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, historical

Years ago computer security analysts Dan Farmer and Wietse Venema wrote the security program S.A.T.A.N.

Does anyone know what happened to it (or if it just went out of style) and what people replaced it with, if anything?

Comment: Most people switched to Nessus, which was originally open source, although it isn't now. I looked at SATAN probably 8 years ago now, and it seemed like it was hardly maintained back then.

Comment: Thanks for the response (and the addition of Wietse in the notes, I did not remember)

Comment: A security scanner is only as relevant until the bugs it exploits are relevant.  You're talking about a tool that's 20 years old...

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't my question - just a memory I was curious about. If it were still around and updated or even incorporated into another package that would have been interesting of course. My interest was history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "SATAN has fallen from popularity after the height of its popularity
> in the 1990s. SATAN was released in 1995 and development has ceased.
> In 2006, SecTools.Org conducted a security popularity poll and
> developed a list of 100 network security analysis tools in order of
> popularity based on the responses of 3,243 people. Results suggest[3]
> that SATAN has been replaced by nmap, Nessus and to a lesser degree
> SARA (Security Auditor's Research Assistant), and SAINT."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Administrator_Tool_for_Analyzing_Networks

Comment: Informative, thank you. I had figured it was something like that.